# Prevent users from modifying part of the text in SLComposeViewController

Tags: ios, facebook, twitter, social-framework, slcomposeviewcontroller

Right now, our code is set to grab the text from the **UITextField** as **setInitialText** for Facebook/Twitter posts.

What we want to do is: add an additional permanent message or URL to the Facebook/Twitter posts.

How can we do this?  Here's our current code:

```
[slComposeThirdViewController setInitialText:[[self QText]text]];

[self presentViewController:slComposeThirdViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Just to clarify, we want to keep the text from the **UITextField**, we just want to add the additional permanent message to it.

Comment: I see in your profile that you haven't marked any answers to your question as correct. In case you weren't aware, if an answer has helped you solve a problem, you should mark it as correct by clicking the "check mark" next to the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a little involved, so bear with me here... **and this only works for SLServiceTypeTwitter**

For anyone reading this that is interested in using this, I've put a sample project on Github: https://github.com/NSPostWhenIdle/Immutable-SLComposeViewController

The first thing you'll want to do is make sure that your view controller conforms to `UITextViewDelegate`. You'll also want to create an iVar for a `UITextView`. You won't actually be creating a text view, but you'll want to have a pointer to assign directly to the text view inside the `SLComposeViewController`. While you're here make a iVar for the permanent string as well.

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate> //very important!
{
    UITextView *sharingTextView;
    NSString *permanentText;
}
```

Then in viewDidLoad you can set up what you want the permanent text to be:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    permanentText = @"http://www.stackoverflow.com/";
}
```

The code below is a pretty basic `IBAction` to present the composer with a couple of slight tweaks. First, you'll notice that `setInitialText` uses a formatted string the append the permanent text to the end of the contents of the text field with a space added in between.

Then comes the important part! I've added a loop to `presentViewController:`'s completion handler to cycle through some subviews of subviews of subviews in order to identify the `UITextView` in the composer that contains the sharing text. This needs to be done so you can set that text view's delegate in order to access the `UITextViewDelegate` method `shouldChangeTextInRange`.

```
- (IBAction)exampleUsingFacebook:(UIButton *)sender {

    if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter])
    {
        SLComposeViewController *sharingComposer = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];

        SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler __block completionHandler=^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result){
            [sharingComposer dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        };
        [sharingComposer setCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
        [sharingComposer setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[[self QText]text],permanentText]];

        [self presentViewController:sharingComposer animated:YES completion:^{
            for (UIView *viewLayer1 in sharingComposer.view.subviews) {
                for (UIView *viewLayer2 in viewLayer1.subviews) {
                    if ([viewLayer2 isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]) {
                        for (UIView *viewLayer3 in viewLayer2.subviews) {
                            if ([viewLayer3 isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]]) {
                                [(UITextView *)viewLayer3 setDelegate:self];
                                sharingTextView = (UITextView *)viewLayer3;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

**Important:** Please note that the above will **only** work if placed in the completion handler.

Below is an example of how to set up `shouldChangeTextInRange` to compare the range that the user is attempting to edit to the range that contains your permanent text. By doing so, the user will be able to make changes to any part of the text that they want... except for the part that contains your permanent text. You'll also notice that inside this method I've compared textView to shareingTextView, the pointer we assigned to the text view inside the composer. Doing so will allow you to use other text views within this controller without them following the same rules I've configured for the text view inside the composer.

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    if (textView == sharingTextView) {
        NSRange substringRange = [textView.text rangeOfString:permanentText];
        if (range.location >= substringRange.location && range.location <= substringRange.location + substringRange.length) {
            return NO;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Please don't do this, it can easily break with an update... Roll your own composer and present it.

Comment: How would you do that in swift 3 ? I can't get the UITextView.

Answer (score 2):

You can roll your own composer, append your text and then use SLRequest to actually submit it to the service.

Answer (score 1):

How about capturing the user entered text from the UITextField and then constructing a final string which appends the permanent message you want from it?

```
UITextField *textField;
NSString *enteredText = [textField text];
NSString *finalPost = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ Your permanent text/URL", enteredText];
```

Now post the "finalPost" string to Facebook or Twitter.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Here's the code we implemented and we get **(null)** when posting.  Thanks! `UITextField *QText;`
        `NSString *enteredText = [QText text];`
        `NSString *finalPost = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@test", enteredText];`
        
        `[slComposeThirdViewController setInitialText:finalPost];`

Comment: The idea was to append a fixed text to the text entered in the UITextField. So the fixed text is NOT editable/removable and hence permanent. Am I missing your point? The finalPost string has the fixed text hard coded and thus not editable by the user.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append the text with URL, just use the addURL: method. It won't display any text in the SLComposeViewController's view. But will add the URL at the end after publishing users tweet.

```
SLComposeViewController *slComposeThirdViewController = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
[slComposeThirdViewController setInitialText:@"initial Text"];
[slComposeThirdViewController addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://stackoverflow.com/"]];
```