# Get the user submitted post / tweet using SLComposeViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, twitter, slcomposeviewcontroller

Is there a way to get the user submitted comments upon posting to facebook / twitter when using `SLComposeViewController`?

It seems the completion handler only allows access to the completion statuses '`SLComposeViewControllerResultDone`' or '`SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled`'.

Here is an example snippet of how my code is looking right now:

```
SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];

[tweetSheet setInitialText:@"A test tweet."];

[tweetSheet setCompletionHandler:^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result) {
      //------ get user submitted comments here somehow? ------
}];

[shareViewController presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:^{
      [self dismiss];
}];
```

Comment: Solution which may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13737046/308315

Comment: Did you find a way to capture the resulting tweet? TIA

Comment: @amitsaurav did you find a solution for swift? Cannot find any relevant answer on so.

Comment: @capikaw did you find a solution in swift?