# getting the UITextView from SLComposeViewController when using SLServiceTypeFacebook

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, slcomposeviewcontroller

I am trying to get the UITextView of SLComposeViewController, how do I get it? I tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
  [viewController presentViewController:facebookController
           animated:YES
           completion:^{
               for (UIView *viewLayer1 in facebookController.view.subviews) {
                   for (UIView *viewLayer2 in viewLayer1.subviews) {
                       if ([viewLayer2 isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]) {
                           for (UIView *viewLayer3 in viewLayer2.subviews) {
                               if ([viewLayer3 isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]]) {
                                   [(UITextView *)viewLayer3 setDelegate:self];

                               }
                           }
                       }
                   }
               }               }];
```

FYI the code above works fine if it's a `SLServiceTypeTwitter` but it doesn't work if it's  `SLServiceTypeFacebook`

Comment: You are asking for trouble as soon as that view hierarchy changes.

Comment: What @iWasRobbed said.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [0x7fffffff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/716216/0x7fffffff) managed to get it in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13737046/189804

Note his note: "Important: Please note that the above will only work if placed in the completion handler."

Comment: I had copied the same exact code in his post but it didn't work. If you notice the code above is the same

Comment: I did notice that, are you using it in the completion handler?

Comment: Yes I did.. I just noticed that the above code works for twitter but not for facebook

Comment: Haha, unfortunately I didn't notice until after that post, that this code only works for SLServiceTypeTwitter. Facebook, and Weibo apparently have completely difference view hierarchies.