# how to set text uneditable when posting on facebook using SLComposeViewController in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, facebook, slcomposeviewcontroller

I am integrating Facebook in my application using `SLComposeViewController` for `iOS 6` and I am trying to do is text can not be edit before posting it on Facebook.Now,it is editable,I want to make it uneditable,how can I make the text uneditable? Please help me,Thanks

Comment: I managed to get the described functionality working when using SLServiceTypeTwitter as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13737046/716216 unfortunately I was unable to get it working for Facebook, but maybe the code I wrote will help you figure it out yourself.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SLComposeViewController, there is no API to disable the text from being editable by the user. You can set initial text but ultimately user can still edit the text as he wants to.

> The SLComposeViewController class presents a view to the user to
>   **compose a post** for supported social networking services.
>
> ...
>
> Set the initial content before presenting the view controller to the
>   user. All the methods that set the content of a post return a Boolean
>   value. They return NO if the content doesn’t fit in the post or if the
>   view controller has already been presented to the user. You must set
>   all of the content in the post before presenting the view controller
>   to the user. **After presenting the view controller, only the user can
>   edit the post**.

Please take a look at [SLComposeViewController class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/SLComposeViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012205) to find out all the available methods you can use.

I believe this for the benefit of the users, either users want to personalize the message or because users might find the initial text too agressive.